# Unexpected $end of file

Tags: php, file

I know this is a common problem. But I can't find what's causing it. The code is also 700ish lines. So i'll link a pastebin, http://pastebin.com/UZh8bBHC.
The error is:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in
>   /web/com/138072177427417/main.php on line 729

Comment: Post the **relevant** lines of code here - We do not follow links to pastebin.

Comment: I would but I can't because I have no idea what's causing it. It could be anywhere in there. I am so sorry about this.

Comment: Well any code before the error. Or try to replicate it by isolating a specific part/component. If you don't know anything about the context, how can we?

Comment: @"post relevant code": If you had any idea what this error meant, you would know that that's not possible to post a relevant segment.  The error is thrown at the last line of the file, which means any line could contain that error.  The only available options are "post no code", and "post an external link to code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people won't put in this much effort, but given how negative the response has been, I figured I'd give you a real answer.

Line 241, `if($selection=="users"){` is unmatched, causing the error.  You could have a different (and equivalent issue), but that is the one causing the error.

I found this by copying your code into an IDE (or in my case, vim), going to the last brace, using the "jump to matching bracket" button, which put me at the line after, then saying "well there's a further out opening bracket, so that one is unmatched".

To debug things like this in future, you can also try commenting out large blocks of code that have "matching" parenthesis.  If removing it fixes the problem, that's where your mismatch is.  Alternatively, you can refactor your code to use functions more often -- by modularizing the code, errors are localized to the specific function causing the problem, as opposed to being "anywhere".

Answer (score 2):

This error is indicative of missing at least one closing `}`. Walk through your code again and try to find where this may be.

Answer (score 0):

you lose at least two "}".  Try to indent your code :)

Comment: "Try to indent your code in a systematic way matching your parenthesis".  Just indenting it based on what it should do very well might not find the issue.